# Unable to login with basic auth in Laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5, basic-authentication

I've been trying to get authentication working for an API that I'm making in Laravel 5. I added basic authentication by extending `AuthenticateWithBasicAuth`. When I visit a page in the browser, I get the prompt to login. But when I enter credentials, it's not allowing me in. Here's what I have in my mysql general log from the request:

```
4 Connect   root@localhost on zgrid
4 Query use `zgrid`
4 Prepare   set names 'utf8' collate 'utf8_unicode_ci'
4 Execute   set names 'utf8' collate 'utf8_unicode_ci'
4 Close stmt
4 Prepare   select * from `accounts` where `sid` = ? limit 1
4 Execute   select * from `accounts` where `sid` = 'a' limit 1
4 Close stmt
4 Quit
```

So it's only selecting an account, it's not trying to get the password as well. Now this may be hidden by some lara-magic but my credentials that I enter are correct (copied straight from mysql CLI). Also, it isn't even attempting to do anything with the password. Otherwise, I would see it in my log above. What should I be looking at next? What are my next steps? Anyone have any suggestions? Did I miss something?

Comment: The password is compared direct on the code, not with the select. Check the method ```validateCredentials``` on the class ```DatabaseUserProvider```

Comment: I found the method and I edited to return true to test it. But when I try to access it again I get the same behavior.

Comment: Is your password stored as plain text in the database or is it hashed?

Comment: It's hashed. But, I generate it randomly. The password is actually an authentication token, but I named it password to play nice with basic auth. However, your comment made me realize that it's trying to hash the value I'm giving it, so I need to hash my token first on generation. Thanks @Bogdan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel authentication system assumes that you have stored your passwords hashed. When you attempt to authenticate a user with certain password, it first hashes it and compares it with what is stored in the database. Copying from the mysql console and giving it to the authentication method call will re-Hash the password so they will not be the same. If have stored your password to the database without hashing, the authentication call will still fail. So either store your passwords after a Hash::make('passwordValue') call or if you want the plain password stored use a simple comparison authentication (not secure though)